# How to perform ionic upload from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ionic-view

I have created a basic app using the **new ionic template available for visual studio 2015**. I want to look at the app on iPhone's using ionic View App. **Where can I issue the cli command `ionic upload`?** (PM console and console2 refuse it)

since just typing ionic in the cmd did not work, (unrecognized command) I downloaded and **installed ionic framework** (even though everything in VS2015 ionic was working fine). Then, **if I run ionic upload I get an error**:

```
ordovaProject4\www>ionic upload

TypeError: Invalid Version: Not installed
    at new SemVer (C:\Users\3stra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_mo
dules\semver\semver.js:295:11)
    at Range.test (C:\Users\3stra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_mo
dules\semver\semver.js:1049:15)
    at Function.satisfies (C:\Users\3stra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic
\node_modules\semver\semver.js:1098:16)
    at Object.checkRuntime (C:\Users\3stra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ioni
c\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\info.js:295:32)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\3stra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\cli
.js:54:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\3stra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic
\bin\ionic:9:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

Invalid Version: Not installed (CLI v1.6.4)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: Not installed
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.8
OS: Windows 8.1
Node Version: v0.12.2
```

Comment: just issue it from a normal terminal from the root project. So if you project is called MyProject, cd into it with a normal terminal and run it.

Comment: it does not work. ionic is not a recognized command. So I downloaded and installed ionic framework (even though everything in VS2015 ionic was working fine). Then, if I run ionic upload I get an error

Comment: I started the bounty.  Neither of the new answers really were correct, but I upvoted the closest one so he'll get half the bounty points.

Comment: Thanks. Curious to see what effect that command had though, if only OP would answer. Maybe it has something to do with the working directory or running directory of VS? @Guy what output does `pwd` give you?

Comment: I apologize, but since asking, I have reinstalled windows, and now running VS without the Mobile part (and without space to add it). So I won't be able to provide further feedback as I always do.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see you are missing Cordova CLI, perhaps that is causing the problem?

Try

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Answer (score 1):

did you do ionic login before doing ionic upload? And you are in the WWW directory when doing ionic upload. You have to do that from the root directory.

Comment: I think I didn't login (not from CLI at least). 
I notice in my LastPass that I do have an account. I cannot give updated status on this, since my environment no longer has the mobile parts.